# Generating DTO structs from postgres DB table schemas using xo

Tags: postgresql, go

I was just wondering if anyone has worked with [xo](https://github.com/xo/xo). I have a Postgres DB, with a bunch of tables and stuff.

I can't seem to generate DTO `struct`s from postgres table structures using `xo`.

This builtin `xo` [template](https://github.com/xo/xo/blob/master/templates/postgres.type.go.tpl) seems to create a `struct`, and I believe `xo` uses the built-in templates by default, but all I get when I run

`xo --verbose --suffix '.go' pgsql://myusername:mypass@localhost:myport/mydb?sslmode=disable -o internal/qo/models -p qo`

is a bunch of files which are compl etely unrelated to my project or the schemas in my DB. [image: Screenshot of one of the files and the entire list of generated files on the left]

Answer (score 0):

So from what I've found, the `xo` package's [postgreSQL loader](https://github.com/xo/xo/blob/master/loaders/postgres.go) uses "public" as the default schema, and in my DB, the schema named "public" only has the table named `schema_migrations` and a lot of stored procedures, thus resulting in the above set of appropriately generated code.

On using `--schema <correct_schema_name>` where `<correct_schema_name>` is the schema for which the dto structs are to be generated, the correct code is generated.

So, the correct command is :

`xo --verbose --schema <correct_schema_name> --suffix '.go' pgsql://myusername:mypass@localhost:myport/mydb?sslmode=disable -o internal/qo/models -p qo`

There are also a couple of settings in the [gen.sh](https://github.com/xo/xo/blob/master/loaders/postgres.go) file which have to be changed as well, such as the type information (specifically the default values) in order to generate the structs with the correct field types.

For example, the default type for timestamps is `pq.NullTime` ([pq](https://github.com/lib/pq) is a Golang Driver for PostgreSQL), and is to be changed in the `gen.sh` file in order to set the proper default type.